# how can an android emulator contact the host developing machine in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, networking, tcp, virtualbox

I have a normal simple java program running as a server, waiting for a client to connect with TCP.

On another eclipse project, i'm building an android application. That application has to contact the java program running on the host machine to receive a message.

I can't simply use "localhost" to contact the server becouse, supposedly, the emulator runs behind a virtual router and i'll be accessing the "phone"'s network instead of the host machine's network.

So, what ip should I use to contact the host development machine?

The machine is a linux running on a VirtualBox with an Ip of 10.0.0.5.
I've tried to use that ip on the emulator but even so, I can't establish a connection.

Answer (score 16):

I think you want 10.0.2.2.  Check out the Android Emulator Networking documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to enable port forwarding in order to use any kind of network connection in the emulator. You can do this with the `adb` tool. Check the Android Developer Guides for details.